# Accidentally submitting an answer to a question too soon

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

Just a little UI issue I ran into this morning.

I was typing a reply to a question, and while I was reaching for the ` key on my keyboard I accidentally hit tab. Immediately afterward, before I realized I hit tab (which selected the submit button), I hit space because it was closing my single-line code block. Unfortunately, hitting space on a submit button will submit the form.

Next thing I know, I had one sentence and a single line of code posted in reply to an answer, and within about 1 minute of trying to edit and complete my answer I received 2 down-votes and some comments. I had to delete the answer again and start it over so I wouldn't have a bunch of random down-votes and comments stuck on my answer.

**TL;DR**

Please add a tab-triggered `e.preventDefault()` for the answer textarea.

It's not really a big deal, but it's something that would literally take 5 minutes for you developers to fix.

Comment: That would make it a lot harder for some people to submit answers. `TAB` navigation is generally a good thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please do not do this. The vast majority of people hitting tab expect the behaviour described. We shouldn't break how forms work for everybody to prevent you from accidentally getting two downvotes.

Next time, delete your answer, edit it, and undelete it if you care that much.

> It's not really a big deal, but it's something that would literally take 5 minutes for you developers to fix.

It's not broken, so it can't be fixed. Your suggestion would break it.

Comment: A lot of the people relying on the tab key are those also relying on keyboard navigation: **users with poor or no vision** or **those who find it physically difficult to use a mouse**, among others. This wouldn't just break how forms work for these people - this would remove their ability to answer questions, and create a keyboard navigation trap lurking for them toward the end of the page.

Comment: I did not think about that. I agree to not want this since it causes other problems I didn't think about.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told everything is possible with jQuery. Really, it's that amazing. We can even modify [Google's behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780809/real-link-to-file-in-google-search-results), mind you.

For this small adjustments in the UI to match our taste, it's a matter of creating [our own Userscripts](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info):

> Userscripts are predominantly privileged JavaScript that runs in a web browser and modifies a web site's behavior and/or appearance. See [the userscripts wiki on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info).

See the watch under the favorite star? jQuery magic, and takes me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/199903/timeline).

> [image: don't remove the tabs, use jQuery]

Just [dig into Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script) for some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be sure to look into userscripts.

Comment: Needs more jQuery.

Comment: @TimPost, that's the Dark Side of jQuery, one never knows when it's enough...